# Return the unique list of values based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with two columns that are alpha-numeric and would like to return all unique values from column "Terms Name" whenever in the column "Terms" the string "Error" appears:

[image]

The code I have come up with is as follows, but it only works when there is just one instance of value "Error" in column "Terms":

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx')
print(df.loc[df['Terms'].str.contains('Error', flags = re.IGNORECASE, na=False), 'Terms Name'].item())
```

When there are more values "Error" than one (like in my df above) I am getting the error: "ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar" and I just can't make it return the correct values: "20th NM" and "NET 45".

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html?highlight=unique#pandas.Series.unique) together with your filtering condition:

```
print(list(df['Terms Name'].loc[df['Terms'].str.contains('Error', flags = re.IGNORECASE, na=False)].unique()))
```

Output:

```
['20th NM', 'Net 45']
```

**Details:**

- `df['Terms Name'].loc[...]` helps filter the condition
- `df['Terms'].str.contains('Error', flags = re.IGNORECASE, na=False)`  retains your filtering condition
- `....unique()`  the filtered subset of `df['Terms Name']` is called with `Series.unique()` to get ndarray of the unique values
- `list(...)`  convert the resulting ndarray to Python list

If you just need to print the result rather than want to get a Python list of the unique values, you can skip the last step using `list(...)`

Comment: Thank you very much. Great stuff!